# Use Sedis pool is Play! Framework object

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, jedis, playframework-2.4

From Play! 2.4 (Scala) Sedis plugin should be injected in class using:

```
class TryIt @Inject()(sedisPool: Pool) extends Controller {
   val directValue: String = sedisPool.withJedisClient(client => client.get("someKey"))
}
```

But I need to use it in Scala object (I'm writing authorization filter, ani it need to be an object).
Is it possible?

Comment: Take a look at the answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see it, you are using the [Sedis play plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/redis) which supports the Guice injection model. However, if you use only [Sedis](https://github.com/pk11/sedis), independent of the plugin, you can instantiate it as any other object, like this:

```
val pool = new Pool(new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "localhost", 6379, 2000))
```

Edit:
I just checked, it is completely ok to also inject the `Pool` into a filter. I tried it.

```
class ExampleFilter @Inject() (sedisPool: Pool) extends Filter {
override def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(rh: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = 
 {
    println(this.sedisPool)
    //do your stuff.
    nextFilter(rh)
 }
}
```

This is possible because the filter sequence is also [injected with Guice in 2.4.x.](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaHttpFilters#Using-filters)